# silverlight Application can not use wcf namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application with a web application to test it,
there are two WCF services I created on my web application.
I can add reference all my services in my Silverlight application but when I want to use one of my data contracts ,I can not add my service namespace to the Silverlight application:

ex: I have a person class in my WCF service(reference name)
WCF service.person  = new wcfservice.person();

Error:

> The type or namespace name 'WCF service' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I have this error too:   Error 6 Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'WCFservice'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details. D:\....\WCFservice\Reference.svcmap 1 1 appname

Answer (score 0):

> I can add reference all my services in my Silverlight application but
>   when I want to use one of my data contracts...

You can't bring in the namespace because it exists in an assembly which has been complied in a different CLR. But that doesn't mean one can't work with the defined class. By bringing the target class(es) into the Silverlight project via the use of a *linked file* one can safely work around the CLR differences.

A linked file is built in both projects, the original and the linked, but only resides in one location; hence changes made to it are reflected in both projects.

In the Silverlight project `add` the target file(s) and then choose:

[image]

That way you can use the class within the namespace as such, for it is compiled into the Siliverlight programs scope; but any changes made to the file are also reflected in the Silverlight app.

Comment: it was working last year. now I am going to update it and I see this error . in other sample projects it works.    it is a Silverlight-WCF enabled